# Is it ok to change request.POST._mutable

Tags: django

Django 1.11.2

Do you think this is a good style or not:

In CBV:

```
request.POST._mutable = True
request.POST['{}_date_day'.format(prefix)] = ceil_day(day=day, month=month, year=year)
request.POST._mutable = False
```

The program works well. I'm satisfied. What troubles me is whether this is ok or not. Maybe it is really a bad practice.

I mean, is it acceptable that we should change the private property _mutable?

Comment: Its not a good practice. If you really want to modify then copy that object then do modifications

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Rather than modifying POST, you should probably be doing this logic in a form or serializer's clean method.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, I use SelectDateWidget in a search form. This means that nothing is saved. But if the data from user are invalid (say, 31st of February), I'd like to substitute it with the last day of the month (28th or 29th depending on the year). If I do this in a form, I'll not be able to preserve user's input. That is why I decided to change request.POST.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at form [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values). I don't get you approach, if the user input is correct you are completely overriding it?

Comment: Todor, yes, I really override the user input. Have you seen SelectDateWidget? I just substitute the last day of the month if a user inputs wrong day. It is much more user friendly approach than plain SelectDateWidget. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to a Form is simply a dictionary, it's not necessary to use the `request.POST` querydict, and it's a bad practice to interfere with the inner workings of the framework, you'll make your code much more portable if you do:

```
my_querydict = request.POST.copy() #creates a mutable copy
my_querydict['{}_date_day'.format(prefix)] = ceil_day(day=day, month=month, year=year)
form = WhateverForm(my_querydict)
```

You'll feel better about yourself later :-)

Comment: That will not work. You can try it yourself. This way: data = request.POST.dict()

Comment: I'll edit with a new approach